# How to convert list with multiple columns to data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a list object called results. This list contains 2 list, each of those list also have multiple columns. I would like to convert it to data frame that combine those columns on each list. I know that we can't combine columns with different length, so is there any way to put NA's for the extra observations. 
here is a small portion of the list object (results)

```
results         
[[1]]           
         gene_name  x1                         x2
gene34556    gene1             0                0
gene11169    gene2   0.098757012                0
gene11319    gene3             0                0
gene1459     gene3             0                0
gen168232    gene5             0                0
gene2992     gene6   -1.93960816      0.042291503
gene305454   gene7             0                0
gene3280     gene8             0                0

[[2]]           
            gene_name          x1             x2
gene34556   gene1               0              0
gene11169   gene2    -3.785515694              0
gene11319   gene3               0              0
gene1459    gene4               0              0
gene2992    gene5    -2.308363477   -0.267514619
```

Comment: Please provide reproducible data and expected output.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you `dput(results)`?

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear how you would like to combine your observations for your list since you have similar gene names in both lists. But here are a few ways you can combine both elements in your list into a single dataframe:

```
library(data.table)

result <- list(data.frame(gene_name=c("a","b","c"),
                          x1 = rnorm(3),
                          x2 = rnorm(3), 
                          row.names=c("gene34556","gene11169","gene11319"),
                          stringsAsFactors = F), 
               data.frame(gene_name=c("a","b","c", "x"),
                          x1 = rnorm(4),
                          x2 = rnorm(4),
                          row.names=c("gene34556","gene11169","gene11319","gene3280"),
                          stringsAsFactors = F))


# combine list "vertically"
rbindlist(result)
#    gene_name         x1          x2
# 1:         a  0.3522310 -0.31057642
# 2:         b -0.7110728  1.12948383
# 3:         c -1.6032146 -0.87341353
# 4:         a -0.1599496 -1.03543084
# 5:         b -0.1081441  1.93735177
# 6:         c  0.9923114 -0.02319378
# 7:         x -0.8283895  0.72096001

# merge both dataframes within the list:
base:::merge(result[[1]], result[[2]], by="gene_name", all=TRUE)
#   gene_name       x1.x       x2.x       x1.y        x2.y
# 1         a  0.3522310 -0.3105764 -0.1599496 -1.03543084
# 2         b -0.7110728  1.1294838 -0.1081441  1.93735177
# 3         c -1.6032146 -0.8734135  0.9923114 -0.02319378
# 4         x         NA         NA -0.8283895  0.72096001
```

If the dataframes in the list need to be merged based on the rownames, then use by=0:

```
# merge both dataframes within the list:
base:::merge(result[[1]], result[[2]], by=0, all=TRUE)
#   Row.names gene_name.x       x1.x       x2.x gene_name.y       x1.y        x2.y
# 1 gene11169           b -0.1694079  2.1168323           b  2.0969813  0.82247288
# 2 gene11319           c  1.5375766 -1.4373368           c  2.0990688 -0.06107935
# 3  gene3280        <NA>         NA         NA           x  0.2528695  1.66448111
# 4 gene34556           a -0.5648451 -0.4891148           a -0.1783414  0.10531560
```

**EDIT:**

In case of multiple dataframes in the list:

```
result <- list(data.frame(gene_name=c("a","b","c"),
                          x1 = rnorm(3),
                          x2 = rnorm(3), 
                          row.names=c("gene34556","gene11169","gene11319"),
                          stringsAsFactors = F), 
               data.frame(gene_name=c("a","b","c", "x"),
                          x1 = rnorm(4),
                          x2 = rnorm(4),
                          row.names=c("gene34556","gene11169","gene11319","gene3280"),
                          stringsAsFactors = F), 
               data.frame(gene_name=c("a","c", "x"),
                          x1 = rnorm(3),
                          x2 = rnorm(3),
                          row.names=c("gene34556","gene11319","gene3280"),
                          stringsAsFactors = F))

# add rownames as a column
new.result <- lapply(result, FUN=function(x){y=cbind(row_name=rownames(x),x, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)})

# merge using base merge() function 
new.result %>%
  Reduce(function(df1,df2) merge(df1,df2, by='row_name', all=TRUE), .)

# The result is the data frame
   row_name gene_name.x        x1.x       x2.x gene_name.y       x1.y       x2.y gene_name         x1         x2
1 gene11169           b  0.80895379 0.02031943           b -0.3121325  0.7952539      <NA>         NA         NA
2 gene11319           c -1.20666887 1.05976176           c  0.4624013 -0.2617053         c  1.6058288  1.5488336
3 gene34556           a -0.01044742 0.11722414           a -0.2593305  1.2252805         a  0.8526598  0.2695985
4  gene3280        <NA>          NA         NA           x  1.0222144  1.6846108         x -0.1128416 -0.4463099

# For large dataset full_join() from dplyr package might perform faster:
new.result %>%
  Reduce(function(df1,df2) full_join(df1,df2, by='row_name'), .)
#    row_name gene_name.x       x1.x        x2.x gene_name.y       x1.y       x2.y gene_name         x1         x2
# 1 gene34556           a  0.8141012 -0.27145107           a -0.1113020 -0.1708712         a -0.4537174 -1.0222622
# 2 gene11169           b -0.2260749  0.09578933           b -1.7803083 -0.9246307      <NA>         NA         NA
# 3 gene11319           c  2.3439445 -1.11945962           c  0.3269329 -1.6452048         c -1.0486770  0.5048081
# 4  gene3280        <NA>         NA          NA           x -1.7521306  0.7690779         x -1.3238697  0.4762742
```

Comment: I want to combine both elements in the list like that when you used merge function. I would like also to have the list row names as the column names for merging  both of them (uniquely  column). please see the I adjusted above. Is there any way to keep the column names as they are after merging them.

Comment: @Mark, It's not clear what you want to get as a result. How you want to incorporate rownames of the original data into the column names of the output? Also what do you want to happen when you have 3 rows with gene2 in our dataset and 1 row with gene2 for the other dataset. It will be much easier to understand what you want if for the input you provided you will also give the desired output.

Comment: Katia, What I want to do as follows: 1: I need to merge the two lists inside the main list in one data frame. I want to merge the using the the first column (the list row names). The gene name column is not important for me that's why I asked to merge them by the list row names.

Comment: OK. Let me do this.

Comment: @Mark: I added this to my answer

Comment: Katia, It worked good. The other question now, How can we generalize that when we have more than list inside the main list (ex: 100 list)

Comment: @Mark, If this answers your main question on this page, please "accept" it as an answer. I will try to "generalize" it and will send you the directions.

Comment: new.result <- lapply(result, FUN=function(x){y=cbind(row_name=rownames(x),x)})
  
new.result %>%
  Reduce(function(df1,df2) merge(df1,df2, by='row_name', all=TRUE), .)

Comment: There is also full_join() function from dplyr that will do the same but might work faster for very large datasets. The output will be need to be converted back to a dataframe if you need to have dataframe object back

Comment: @Mark. I also updated the answer where I provide both approaches - using merge and full_join. It looks like you are working with genes and I suspect your datasets are large. In this case full_join might work better for you.